# Fetching column data from 3 table with Relation table in-between as mediator in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch **category name** too. I have following table

**Product Table**

```
mysql> describe prod;
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pid      | int(4) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| pro_name | varchar(32)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Category Table**

```
mysql> describe cat;
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cid      | int(4) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cat_name | varchar(32)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**`cat_pro`** Table [ Relation Table ]

```
mysql> describe cat_pro;
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cat_id   | int(4) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pro_id   | int(4) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My **Current** `Query` :-

```
mysql> select pid, pro_name, cat_pro.cat_id 
       from prod 
       left join cat_pro on cat_pro.pro_id=prod.pid 
       where pid='2';
```

But when i run this command, it gives me **error** saying `unknown column cat_pro.cat_id in on clause`

```
mysql> select pid, pro_name, cat_pro.cat_id, cat.cat_name 
       from prod 
       left join cat_pro on cat_pro.pro_id=prod.pid 
       left join cat on cat.cid=cat_pro.cat_id 
       where pid='2'
```

Is there any way, I can fetch **category name** too from `cat` table ? , or do i have to run another `query` for fetching **category name** from `cat` table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query:

```
select pid, pro_name, cat_pro.cat_id, cat.cat_name
from
prod
    inner join
cat_pro
    on (cat_pro.pro_id = prod.pid)
    inner join
cat
    on (cat.cid = cat_pro.cat_id)
where pid='2';
```

works without errors for the db structure you provided

Comment: Oh my god! you did it Sir, Thanks :) Will be able to accept this answer in 4 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helpful to you. In below query we are using sub-query to get category name based on category_id.

```
 select 
 prod.pid, 
 prod.pro_name, 
 cat_pro.cat_id,
 (
    select 
        cat_name
    from 
        Category c
    where 
        c.cid = cat_pro.cat_id

 ) as category_name

 from 
 prod left join 
 cat_pro on cat_pro.pro_id=prod.pid 
 where prod.pid='2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `pid`, `pro_name`, `c`.`cat_id`
FROM `prod` `p`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cat_pro` `c` ON `c`.`pro_id` = `p`.`pid`
WHERE `p`.`pid` = 2;
```